# gazebo starting view pose control

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

ı want to change gazebo first starting view pose on my model. When gazebo first started, ı want to see my world above.I dont want always change my world view with mouse. how can I change gazebo initial view pose in .world file.

so :

my first view: [http://i.imgur.com/qTkYEJc.png](https://i.imgur.com/qTkYEJc.png)

BUT: I want to see like this first starting.

[http://i.imgur.com/ouqEYEi.png](https://i.imgur.com/ouqEYEi.png)

what can ı do in my sdf file ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9238/gazebo-starting-view-pose-control/) by [osmancns](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1334/osmancns/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can set the [user camera pose](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=world#gui_camera) in the SDF as follows:

```
<world name="default">
  <gui>
    <camera name="user_camera">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    </camera>
  </gui>
...
</world>
```

From Gazebo 6, you can find out the [current camera pose](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-requests/1649/get-set-user-camera-pose-in-gui-1595/diff) on the World tab, under GUI. Then you can use that value in your SDF.

On older versions of Gazebo, you can save your world with the desired camera pose and find the pose in the saved SDF.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2